# Check first install and registry value not exists in Wix

Tags: wix

```
 <![CDATA[(NOT Installed) AND (ACCESSRUNTIMECHECK <> "Access.Application.12")]]>
```

I was using the above expression to check if I am installing the first time and also if the ACCESSRUNTIMECHECK (a property from registry) value not matching the above value. However its not working correctly. whats wrong?

I am sure that the value of ACCESSRUNTIMECHECK is equal to "Access.Application.12".

```
 <Property Id="ACCESSRUNTIMECHECK">
  <RegistrySearch Id="AccessRuntimeSearch" 
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\Classes\Access.Application\CurVer"
                  Type="raw"  />

</Property>

<Condition Message="Access not installed!">
  <![CDATA[(NOT Installed) AND (ACCESSRUNTIMECHECK <> "Access.Application.12")]]>
 </Condition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression has to evaluate to true to allow installation.  The "or Installed" is meant to prevent the lack of Access from interfering with a repair / uninstall.

```
<Condition Message="Access not installed!">
  ACCESSRUNTIMECHECK ~= &quot;Access.Application.12&quot; Or Installed
</Condition>
```